# Does there always exist a sub sequence which converges to an arbitrary number between limit superior and limit inferior of a bounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

For a bounded sequence $\{x_n \}$ with limit superior $x^*$ and limit inferior $x_*$, there exists two subsequences of $\{x_n\}$ which converge to $x^*$ and $x_*$ respectively. It also holds true that the limit of any convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ lies within $[x_*,x^*]$.

I was wondering if the following is also true.

> For every $c \in  [x_*,x^*]$, there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which converge to $c$

I have no idea about the above, any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: An interesting follow-up question could be, is there a sequence for which this holds?

Comment: @Raptor one can easily construct such sequence with that property, did you post the question?

Comment: @Raptor: Pick a min and max.  Then put in the midpoint between them.  Then put in the quarters between them, then put in the eighths between them, et c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No take $x_n=(-1)^n$. Zero lies between $-1$ and $1$ which are $\liminf  x_n$ and $\limsup x_n$ respectively, but zero is not a subsequential limit, since $x_n\notin (-1,1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

No, as @Shashi showed with the alternating $-1,1$ sequence. What *is* true, for any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ seen inside the two-point compacification $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty, +\infty]$ that $$S = \{s \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}: \text{ there is a subsequence } x_{n_k} \to s\}$$

is closed (and thus compact) in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ so $\min(S) = \liminf_n x_n$ and $\limsup_n x_n = \max(S)$ exist. So $S \subseteq [\liminf x_n, \limsup x_n]$  but not conversely, $S$ could just be a finite set, as in the alternating sequence case.